# Optional param in rails path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this conditional:

```
if(request.fullpath != '/')
  redirect_to login_path(:redirect_url => view_context.b64_encode(request.fullpath)) unless current_user
else
  redirect_to login_path unless current_user
end
```

Which basically says only add the `:redirect_url` param if the request is not the root url. However it's meant repeating the redirect and unless code... Is it possible to make that param optional like a ternary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work (with a ternary operator):

```
unless current_user
  redirect_to login_path(request.fullpath == '/' ? {} : { :redirect_url => view_context.b64_encode(request.fullpath) })
end
```

This also should work:

```
unless current_user
  redirect_to login_path(({ :redirect_url => view_context.b64_encode(request.fullpath) } if request.fullpath != '/'))
end
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I just tried literally as you posted your answer.

Comment: Added one more option (without ternary operator)

Answer (score 0):

This was the best I came up with: `redirect_to login_path(request.fullpath != '/' ? {:redirect_url => view_context.b64_encode(request.fullpath)} : {}) unless current_user`